# delay in firing DOMContent

Tags: jquery, performance, load, html

I am trying to improve my site response time and found that there is a delay between the last file load (3.11 sec) and firing of DOMContent and then load event (4.72 sec). pic added.

It seems that it might be due to JS processing, which I have placed in the footer instead of head.

I would like to know how can I analyze this delay and plug it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline

And in **DOMContentLoaded and Load event markers** section :

> https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline-images/image28.png
>   The Timeline annotates each recording with a blue and a red line that
>   indicate, respectively, when the DOMContentLoaded and load events were
>   dispatched by the browser. The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when
>   all of the page’s DOM content has been loaded and parsed. The load
>   event is fired once all of the document’s resources (images and CSS
>   files, and so forth) have been fully loaded

You should concat all your javascript files in one javascript file, and all css files in one css file. Also you should gzip (compress) your files.

Try [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) (based on nodejs) , or [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (based on java), to do some automatic tacks (minify, compress, concat, etc). Others automatic tasks softs exists.